# Processing strings with toupper() causing an infinite loop

Tags: c++, argv

I'm trying to write a program to convert one letter of each word to uppercase. `argv[1]` is a number like 3. If `argv[1]` is  `3`, only the third letter of each word should be uppercase and the others lowercase.

I wrote this disaster of a code, and it's stuck in an infinite loop that only displays the first input char repeatedly.

I need help with the logic.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c;  // yes, read chars in as ints.
    int ncounter = atoi(argv[1]);
    int cchecker = 0;

    c = cin.get();
    while (!cin.eof()) 
    {
        if (c == ' ')
        {
            cchecker = 0;
        }
        else 
        {
            if (cchecker == ncounter) 
            {
                c = (toupper(c));
                cchecker++;
            }
            else 
            {
                c = (tolower(c));
                cchecker++;
            }
        }

        cout.put('\n'); // sometimes this is needed: you'll know when
    }
}
```

**Update** here's new code, it works almost perfect, except it sometimes doesn't uppercase the first word, kinda strange.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c ;  // yes, read chars in as ints.
    int ncounter = atoi(argv[1]);
    int cchecker = 0;

    c = cin.get() ;
    while (!cin.eof())
    {
        if (c == ' ')
        {
            cchecker = 0;
            cout.put (c);
            c = cin.get ();
            cchecker++;
        }
        else
        {
            if (cchecker == ncounter)
            {
                cout.put (toupper(c));
                c = cin.get() ;
                cchecker++;
            }
            else
            {
                cout.put (tolower(c));
                c = cin.get() ;
                cchecker++;
            }
        }
    }
    cout.put('\n') ; // sometimes this is needed: you'll know when
}
```

Comment: Of course it displays "the first input int", because the shown code calls `cin.get();` just once, at first, and then keeps looping forever, each time checking if `cin.eof()`, and if not, just does something and checks again, expecting `cin`'s status to somehow change, even though nothing else has been read from it. You might want to spend a few minutes cleaning up the shown code's indentation. By making the shown code's indentation logical, and consistent, the logical flaw would be more readily visible, and obvious.

Comment: `ncounter` is 1-based, but `cchecker` is 0-based, so you have 1-off errors. When (re)initializing `cchecker`, use 1 instead of 0

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> while (!cin.eof())
> ```

Your loop condition states, that the loop ends if eofbit of the standard input stream (represented by the `std::cin` object) was set in the last iteration. Eofbit would be set upon reading from the standard input when there is no more characters there.

> it's stuck in an infinite loop

Your loop never reads from the standard input, and therefore the state of the loop condition can never change. If the loop is entered, it will never stop.

Comment: That's as intended, please stay on topic

Comment: @Kiril if your intention is to be stuck in an infinite loop, then I suppose you don't have a problem in the first place?

Comment: Yes, not the problem you’re answering at least. The updated code outputs as intended. I am having white space problems now. If you ran or looked at the updated code, you would see that. This is a homework assignment, it is intended to loop as many times as needed for the professor to grade the logic. The infinite loop is not the issue. The original issue was that it was only outputting one char repeatedly. Second set of code fixes that, now the issue is whitespace control and argv not casting toupper onto the first word reliably. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you are reading from `std::cin` only one time, before entering the loop, so you get stuck in an infinite loop because you never call `cin.get()` again inside the loop so `cin.eof()` has a chance to change value.  Though, you should consider using `while (cin.get(ch))` instead of `while (!cin.eof())`.

But, why are you reading from `std::cin` one `char` at a time to begin with?  You say you want to change letters in words, so you should be reading whole words, not individual characters.

Try using `operator>>` in a loop to read a whole word, replacing the Nth `char` in that word, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>

char my_toupper(char ch)
{
    return std::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch));
}

char my_tolower(char ch)
{
    return std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ncounter = std::atoi(argv[1]);
    std::string word;

    while (cin >> word)
    {
        std::transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), my_tolower);
        if (word.size() >= ncounter)
            word[ncounter-1] = my_toupper(word[ncounter-1]);
        std::cout << word << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```